# Not able to create new dir with file using resources in vb.net

Tags: microsoft-excel, embedded, resources, vb.net

```
Dim sPath As String

    sPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))

    For i = 1 To 50
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Application.DoEvents()

    Next

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx") Then
        Dim APP As New Excel.Application
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        APP.Visible = False
        MessageBox.Show("File Opened!" & Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
    Else
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx", My.Resources.StoredInformation, True)
        Dim APP As New Excel.Application
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        APP.Visible = False
        MessageBox.Show("File Created!" & Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
    End If
```

It's not creating my folder "Housing" or my file "Stored Information.xlsx"
Could someone please take a look and tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: This question is off-topic here and belongs to SO (stackoverflow.com)

Comment: i dont see how it can be off topic if it's related to software ?

Comment: It's 50/50. It's some VBA you run from within excel, right? So that would make it software related. Otherwise it's a programming question which would be Stackoverflow. Anyway do you get any error messages or is the result just that's not created? What does `My.Resources.StoredInformation` contain?

Comment: No error messages appear. It's an excel document that contains headings in four coloumns. My program writes to that excel file and fills each coloumn with values.

Comment: It just skips it for some reason, the code is located in the load event

Comment: It skips what? The whole else block, method or what? How did you determine "it" gets skipped? And what's the content of `My.Resources.StoredInformation`?

Comment: @Seth - when i meant it "Skips" i mean that it seems that it just doesn't execute the whole "IF" statement. I even checked if there was a new folder created in my documents and there wasn't one. By 'Content' do you mean what type of file is it?

Comment: @Seth - i published my program and then installed it, when i started the program an error appeared and it said that;    System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\ARROW-ASSASSIN\Documents\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx'

Comment: Your snippet doesn't have any indication of what `My.Resources.StoredInformation` if it was 0 Bytes that `WriteAllBytes` maybe doesn't create the file. That was my thought. Did you include some debug output or use actual debugging tools like breakpoints and step by step execution to check which parts of that if are executed? Is the path in that error message correct?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by "0 Bytes that `WriteAllBytes` ". The file was created when i changed the path to my desktop and removed the folder "Housing" so the path would be "C:\Users\ARROW-ASSASSIN\Desktop\Stored Information.xlsx " but then the file would be damaged. All i do is run the 'debug' mode to start my program. I'm still a noob when it comes vb.net

Answer (score 1):

Eventually got it right. The key was to use `CreateDirectory()` to create the entire directory path including the `Housing` directory at the bottom of the hierarchy.

```
Dim sPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Housing")
Dim Fpath As String = sPath & "\Stored Information.xlsx"

IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath) ' If location already exists it will not do anything

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Fpath) = False Then
   My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(Fpath, My.Resources.StoredInformation, True) ' Don't want to append data (although that would not happen in this instance) so True is used for that.
End If

Dim APP As New Excel.Application
workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(Fpath)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
APP.Visible = False
MessageBox.Show("File Opened!" & Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & Fpath)
```